# Alexa Nodejs sdk - What does withSimpleCard() do?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am following the alexa nodejs sdk [tutorial in amazon](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/wiki/Developing-Your-First-Skill)

The sample code has this line in all the responses -

```
 .withSimpleCard('Hello World', speechText)
```

I checked the function definition file, it says :

> Renders a simple card with the following title and content

Can some one please explain what this means ?
What is a card in alexa ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cards allow you to show visual content that complements Alexa's speech. For example the "Now Playing" card displays a song's name and playback controls. In your case it's just a simple text card.

[image]